# How to keep permission for migrating Files and Directories from one linux to another

Tags: files, tar, command

I need to migrate files and directories from one machine to another using tar. I would like to use tar or something similar. But I don't have a root permission. As far as I know "To extract file permissions and ownership, you will need to run tar as root when extracting, since changing file ownership usually requires superuser privileges." https://superuser.com/questions/838392/how-to-tar-a-directory-preserving-not-only-permissions-but-ownership-too

Real situation:

We have the account `mvbat` with the home directory `/home/mvbat`. Within this directory, there are subdirectories and files with varying permissions, some being executable and others not.

We are faced with the task of migrating from the old RedHat6 to the new RedHat8, but there are limitations imposed by the administrator.

As a development team, we are not allowed to use `rsync` for the migration.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to preserve? What are the specific commands you're running right now, and in what way are they **not** working as you would like?

Comment: @larsks I would like to use tar command. And have a script to check the file permissions after migration. Not sure if this can be done easily.

Comment: If you don't have root/sudo on the destination PC, what you're asking for is **impossible**, period.

Comment: Are you trying to copy a single user's files, or files owned by multiple different users? Please update your question to answer this and to provide responses to the other questions asked of you in these comments

Comment: Make it easy for people to help you by having all the information in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you even try it?

To change file ownership you need root privileges (naturally), but preserving permissions is possible without that.

Your "receiving" tar will not be able to change the file ownership if it differs from the uid under which it is run, but it will dutifully preserve permissions (note that umask setting may be applied, to avoid that, either use the `-p` option or change umask to `0` before extracting).

Answer (score 0):

To maintain permissions when migrating files and directories from one Linux machine to another, you can use the rsync command with the -a (archive) option. This option preserves various attributes of the files, including permissions, ownership, timestamps, and symbolic links.

Here's an example command that you can use:

basic
Copy

```
rsync -a /path/to/source/ user@remote:/path/to/destination/
```

In this command, replace /path/to/source/ with the path to the directory that you want to migrate, and user@remote:/path/to/destination/ with the destination server's hostname or IP address, the username you're using to connect to the remote server, and the path to the destination directory.

Note that you'll need to have SSH access to the remote server, and the destination directory must exist on the remote server before running the command.

Comment: rsync or ssh command cannot be used due to the policy.

Comment: rsync will be unable to set ownership correctly unless it's running with enough privilege on the destination end (or the target user is same as originating user).

Answer (score 0):

If you have physical access to both machines, use an external drive with ext-type FS.

`cp -a` will preserve all relevant information.